# Using potentiometer in two separate circuits

Tags: arduino, potentiometer

I am building a circuit with Arduino to control the motion of a stepper motor.

I want to use my guitar amp potentiometers to feed voltages back into the Arduino without disassembling the original amp circuit.

Is this possible? How can it be achieved?

Comment: That depends a lot on where the pots are in the amplifier circuit, and what voltages and signals they carry (and what you want the Arduino to see from them).  In other words, you haven't given enough information for anyone to make even  a wild guess.

Comment: Why pots? There a CNC shield . Get that, GRBL code then GRBL Panel for Windows . Awesome

Comment: You want the pot to continue to function simultaneously as an audio control? Almost certainly not. Your best bet may be to couple another pot or absolute encoder mechanically to the existing one, or replace it with a dual pot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are proposing is very unlikely to work. Your micro-controller ADC (analogue to digital converter) input is expecting a signal in the range 0 to +5 V. For a potentiometer input this will be wired as shown in Figure 2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7VMOx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A potentiometer connected to a micro-controller ADC input.*

A guitar amplifier, on the other hand, consists of an AC signal pre-amplifier with tone and volume controls feeding into the main amplifier stage. The guitar signal with high-output pickup at full volume might put out a signal of +/-1 V peak. You can't have this voltage on the potentiometers at the same time as using it for a 0 to 5 V signal.

In the example shown the op-amp is fed from a single-ended supply. We know this because there is a ground symbol on the negative supply pin and a positive connection on the other. The DC+ is likely to be in the range of 12 to 18 V. To allow the output to swing positive and negative we need to bias the output to mid-supply. That's the purpose of R5 and R6. So on a 12 V system the quiescent voltage on the output would be 6 V. Since this is fed back to the potentiometers you can see that the voltages on the pots will be about 6 V with the guitar signal superimposed on it.

[image]

*Figure 2. A Baxandall tone control stage typical of many guitar amplifier pre-amp stages. Source: [Learn About Electronics](http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/Amplifiers/amplifiers42.php).*